# Extracting value from nested json with different formats

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to extract specific values from a column with nested jsons.

Thus is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.response.apply(json.loads))
```

However this returns the following error message:

> JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 29996
>   (char 29995)

Just to clarify I would ideally want to extract the value that has been assigned to a specific key (i guess I tried flattening the json with my code).

Here is a sample of the data that I have in my column (let's call it response:

```
'{"at":"cop","b1":{"B2":"200000000","B3":"ABCDE ART","B4":"21000","B5":"CURRENT","B6":"1234567890"},"B7":"Yes","verified":true,"B8":"2010-11-02T11:10:18.471Z","B9":true,"B10":false,"B11":true,"B12":false,"B13":true,"accountAcceptsDebits":true,"B14":true,"B15":{"B16":"2010-11-02T11:10:18","response":{"B17":"ok","pagination":{},"body":{"response":{"result_status":"complete","registration_number_match":"Y","company_name_match":"N","account_type_match":"Y","account_open":"Y","account_length_match":"Y","account_found":"Y","account_accepts_debits":"Y","account_accepts_credit":"Y"},"request":{"B20":"1111-1111-1111-1111-1111","B21":"1111111111","B22":"ABCDE","B23":"11111","B24":"CUR","B25":"111111111"}},"attachments":[]},"B26":"111111-11111-1111-1111-1111111"},"B27":"11111-1111-1111-1111-111111","Thisthat":{"version":"1.1.0","timestamp":"2010-11-02T11:11:17"}}'
```

Another example of a row that seems to be causing an error when I run the code in the answers given:

```
{"B1":{"B2":"requires_action","B3":[{"B4":"STATUS CODES -- 3.3","B5":"Code - 38 - AR De-Process"}],"B6":"checks","B7":{"workingMemory":{"B8":1111111111,"B9-NAME-VERIFIED":true,"B10":"F","B11":true,"B12":true,"B13":true,"B14":true,"B15":{"B16":"5123","B17":"ANYPERSON","B18":"Man","B19":"FID","B20":"NDOF","B21":"212121","B22":"","B23":"N","B24":"N","B25":"N","B26":"Y","B27":"Member","B28":"111111","B29":"","B30":"","B31":"","B32":"YES","B33":"11111","B34":"N","B35":"","B36":{"string":["","","",""]},"B37":{"string":["","","",""]},"B38":"","B39":"","B40":"11111111111"},"B41":true},"B42":[{"rule":{"B43":"B44 -- 3.1.1"},"B45":{"B46":true,"B47":"F","B48":111111111,"B49":true},"result":{"B50":"true","overridden":false}},{"rule":{"name":"B51 -- 3.3.2"},"workingMemoryUpdates":{"B52":true},"result":{"exitValue":"true","overridden":false}},{"rule":{"name":"sdsfd -- 3.3.3"},"workingMemoryUpdates":{},"result":{"rtert":"true","message":"No principal member defaults/judgements found","overridden":false}},{"rule":{"name":"etwrtret -- 3.2.1"},"B60":{"dfdsffds":true},"result":{"B61":"true","message":" Anon # Anon report: Thsi: Names: Whatssomethi thig                ","B62":false}},{"rule":{"name":"B63 -- 3.1.4"},"workingMemoryUpdates":{"B64":true},"result":{"exitValue":"true","message":"ID Number is valid","overridden":false}},{"rule":{"name":"wrtrtrtr-- 3.3.1"},"workingMemoryUpdates":{"retertetr":true,"B67":{"B68":"5123","B69":"ASAK","B70":"SDSDS","B71":"DSDS","B72":"SDSD","B73":"122222","comment":"","B73":"N","B74":"N","B75":"N","B76":"Y","position":"Member","B77":"111111","B78":"","B79":"","B80":"","deeds":"YES","infoDate":"12121","B81":"N","srere":"","B82":{"string":["","","",""]},"B83":{"string":["","","",""]},"B89":"","B90":"","idnumber":"8304040035089"}},"result":{"exitValue":"true","message":"name: This Man Woman perons                  ","overridden":false}}],"pausedRules":[],"referredRules":[{"rule":{"name":"BUSINESS STATUS CODES -- 3.3.15"},"workingMemoryUpdates":{},"result":{"exitValue":"referred","message":"dfdfdfsd - df - dfsd","requirements":[{"key":"business-status-code","name":"ABDSD -sdsds Process","type":"boolean"}],"overridden":false}}]},"requestId":"1111-1111-1111-111-111-11111"}}
```

Comment: What does `df` variable contain?

Comment: df is a dataframe with multiple columns, the response column is the one with multiple nested jsons @zipa

Comment: Okay, what would you like to extract? Is this example of one row of `response` column?

Comment: Could you produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @zipa its an example of one row, from that example I would like to extract the value assigned to the keyword B7

Comment: `df.response.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).get(['B7']))` ..?

Comment: Is this example quoted or like shown? If it's not maybe you could add one line before with `true, false = True, False` to help the parser.

Comment: @zipa like shown

Comment: Have you tried with adding `true, false = True, False`?

Comment: @zipa yeah, getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'response': ['{"at":"cop","b1":{"B2":"200000000","B3":"ABCDE ART","B4":"21000","B5":"CURRENT","B6":"1234567890"},"B7":"Yes","verified":true,"B8":"2010-11-02T11:10:18.471Z","B9":true,"B10":false,"B11":true,"B12":false,"B13":true,"accountAcceptsDebits":true,"B14":true,"B15":{"B16":"2010-11-02T11:10:18","response":{"B17":"ok","pagination":{},"body":{"response":{"result_status":"complete","registration_number_match":"Y","company_name_match":"N","account_type_match":"Y","account_open":"Y","account_length_match":"Y","account_found":"Y","account_accepts_debits":"Y","account_accepts_credit":"Y"},"request":{"B20":"1111-1111-1111-1111-1111","B21":"1111111111","B22":"ABCDE","B23":"11111","B24":"CUR","B25":"111111111"}},"attachments":[]},"B26":"111111-11111-1111-1111-1111111"},"B27":"11111-1111-1111-1111-111111","Thisthat":{"version":"1.1.0","timestamp":"2010-11-02T11:11:17"}}']})

df
#                                            response
#0  {"at":"cop","b1":{"B2":"200000000","B3":"ABCDE...

pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.response.apply(json.loads)).B7
#0    Yes
#Name: B7, dtype: object
```

And given that you have some rows that couldn't be parsed with `json`, you can see which ones they are using:

```
for i, row in df.response.iteritems():
    try:
        pd.io.json.json_normalize(json.loads(row))
    except:
        print(i)
```

Comment: code works but for some reason when I run it on my entire column I keep getting this error message -> JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 29996 (char 29995)

Comment: @Emm I've edited with code for finding rows that cause the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example of one of the rows causing the error to my question